# Working with RabbitMQ inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm using the official Docker [RabbitMQ image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/).
I was following the instructions, runnig the command
`docker run -d -e RABBITMQ_NODENAME=my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`

I added `-p 5672:5672` to the command, even though I'm not completely sure it's needed.

I'm using Python with Pika. The command is `pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=queueServer, credentials=credentials))`

When I run my code from the Docker host machine, everything works just fine.
But when I try the same code from another machine I get an error `AMQPConnectionError: 2.0`.
The code has the docker host name in all the RabbitMQ commands. I made sure that name resolves correctly (using ping)

Is there anything else I need to configure to access RabbitMQ (in the container) remotely?

Comment: "When I run my code from the Docker host machine," what command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was something else blocking my connection.
Running the same container on an Ubuntu VM I can connect from the outside with no problem (given the settings in the question)

Comment: So like after 8 and a half years you still remember on this particular issue what the problem was? That's insane.

Answer (score 1):

Still don't understand why we need that long command instead of just `docker run rabbitmq`